# tikzposter 4 logos title (2 at each side)

Tags: titles, tikzposter

I am trying to place 4 logos two at each side of the title for a poster in tikzposter. Is there any way to overlap the title with the figures? Maybe placing the `\titlegraphic` in a different layer using `\settitle`?

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm, blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm,draft]{tikzposter}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}

\title{\parbox{0.5\linewidth}{\centering My  really  really  really  really  really  really  really  really  long poster TITLE.}}
\author{Name}
\titlegraphic{
\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=5cm]{./myImage.jpg}
 \hfill 
\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=5cm]{./myImage.jpg}
\\% \vspace{5pt} \\
\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=5cm]{./myImage.jpg}
 \hfill 
\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=5cm]{./myImage.jpg}
}

\usetheme{Autumn}\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]{Germany}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{My LIPSUM block}{
  \lipsum[1]
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you seek? According to the manual on page 4-5, you could utilize the parameter determining the vertical distance between the `titlegraphic` and the `title description` `\TP@titlegraphictotitledistance` in the `\setitle` command.

by changing the default value via (within makeatletter ... makeatother)

```
\def\TP@titlegraphictotitledistance{-9cm}   % -9 can be adjusted to one's need
\settitle{ \centering \vbox{
\@titlegraphic \\[\TP@titlegraphictotitledistance] \centering
\color{titlefgcolor} {\bfseries \Huge \sc \@title \par}
\vspace*{1em}
{\huge \@author \par} \vspace*{1em} {\LARGE \@institute}
}}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, 
margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm, blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm,draft
]{tikzposter}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,mwe}
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\makeatletter
\def\TP@titlegraphictotitledistance{-9cm}
\settitle{ \centering \vbox{
\@titlegraphic \\ [\TP@titlegraphictotitledistance] 
\centering
\color{titlefgcolor} {\bfseries \Huge \sc \@title \par}
\vspace*{1em}
{\huge \@author \par} \vspace*{1em} {\LARGE \@institute}
}}
\makeatother

\setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}
%
\title{\parbox{0.5\linewidth}{\centering My  really  really  really  really  really  really  really  really  long poster TITLE.}}
\author{Name}
\titlegraphic{
\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=5cm]{./myImage.jpg}
 \hfill 
\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=5cm]{./myImage.jpg}
\\% \vspace{5pt} \\
\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=5cm]{./myImage.jpg}
 \hfill 
\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=5cm]{./myImage.jpg}
}

\usetheme{Autumn}\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]{Germany}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{My LIPSUM block}{
  \lipsum[1]
}

\end{document}
```